# Disable map zoom on CircleMarker double click in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to disable the zoom on the map when I click in a CircleMarker object, but until now, no success.

This is my code:

```
var myCircle = new L.CircleMarker(new L.LatLng(50.924480, 10.758276), 10).addTo(map);
myCircle.on("click", function () {
    //my click stuff
});
myCircle.on("dblclick", function () {
    //my dblclick stuff
});
```

Everytime the dblclick event is fired, the map is zoomed, how to disable it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try

```
var myCircle = new L.CircleMarker(new L.LatLng(50.924480, 10.758276), 10).addTo(map);
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
```

refer [this document](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ihandler)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this will disable double click zoom completely for the map. Is this what OP wants? I though he wants to disable double click zoom only when double clicking on the marker.

Answer (score 6):

None of the answers above worked for me:

- calling native `ev.originalEvent.preventDefault()` did nothing
- returning `false` neither
- I don't like the `doubleClickZoom`workaround that much (although… it works!)

Using [Leaflet DomEvent](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#domevent) did the job for me:

```js
import { DomEvent } from 'leaflet';

myFeature.on("dblclick", function (ev) {
  DomEvent.stopPropagation(ev)
});
```

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me. When using Leaflet lib directly `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(ev)`.

Answer (score 5):

All answers here are after the Leaflet map object has been initialized.

I'd like to give my take by stating that you can also disable doubleClickZoom during map object initialization.

Note: This will disable doubleClickZoom to the whole map and not just circleMarkers.

```
map = L.map('map', {
      center: [39.8282, -98.5795],
      zoom: 5,
      doubleClickZoom: false
    });
```

P.S. I'm running leaflet version 1.7.1

Comment: Works with mapboxgl as well. Better than accepted answers since it only disables the zoom feature.

Comment: But this will disable doubleclick zoom definitively, which is not in the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Following solution seems to work for me:

```
myCircle.ondblclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
};
```

I have also tried another one, which also works quite well in practice, but I find it a bit hacky:

```
myCircle.on("click", function () {
  map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
  setTimeout(function(){map.doubleClickZoom.enable();}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is here looking for a solution to the use case "I want to zoom in on the map on double-click but not if the double-click happens on an entity", this is how I solved it:

```
const circle = new L.circlemarker(...).addTo(map);
circle.on("dblclick", () => {
  map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

  doSomething();

  setTimeout(() => {
    map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
  }, 1); // Without the timeout the map will still zoom in on entity double-click
});
```

FYI `event.preventDefault();` `event.stopPropagation();` and `return false;` inside the "dblclick" handler did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false` from your dblclick handler which will stop the event from propagating e.g.

```
myCircle.on("dblclick", function () {
    //my dblclick stuff
    return false;
});
```

Now other elements (such as the map) won't handle that event

Answer (score 0):

Try this...  Disable map.doubleClickZoom when you mouse over the circle and enable when you leave

```js
var myCircle = new L.CircleMarker(new L.LatLng(50.924480, 10.758276), 10).addTo(map);

myCircle
    .on("click", function () {
        //my click stuff
    })
    .on("dblclick", function () {
        //my dblclick stuff
    })
    .on('mouseover', function () {
        map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    })
    .on('mouseout', function () {
        map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

First you need to disable the map double click zoom and then enable it again on the map click event. So when you double click the map after double clicking on the marker it zoom again ;) I tried it and it works for me perfectly! Enjoy!

```
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

map.on('click', function (e) { 
  map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
 });
```

Comment: This will enable it forever after 1 click. How does this work perfectly ?